# 64 characters length of mysql MD5?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run:

```
SELECT MD5(  "WhatIsWrongWithThis?" ) AS hash
```

I get a 64 characters long output

```
6631303664616331363338613139623830363332663233656662643635633039
```

that differs from my PHP 32 expected output

```
f106dac1638a19b80632f23efbd65c09
```

- I noticed that my remote mysql is fine.
- Already restarted the mysql service.

[image: local and remote mysql md5 comparison]

**What is happening here?**

---

**UPDATE:**

**Note:** the problem was happening in two levels:

1. PHP/MySQL `SOLVED by reboot`
2. phpMyAdmin `SOLVED by checkbox`

**1. PHP/MySQL**

I had already tried stopping and restarting the mysql server and nothing.. *Then after I rebooted the computer **problem 1. disappeared***.

**STILL HAVE NO IDEA WHY**

**2. phpMyAdmin**

After the answers and comments I saw that indeed the phpMyAdmin had the "Show binary contents as HEX" checkbox checked... **Unchecking it solved the problem 2 phpMyAdmin issue**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When I execute your query I get the same as PHP:

```
HASH
f106dac1638a19b80632f23efbd65c09
```

See this running in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12431)

---

I see what is happening: You are seeing the *hex* of the result, as if you executed

```
SELECT HEX( MD5(  "WhatIsWrongWithThis?" )) AS hash
```

`f` is `66` hex
`1` is `31` hex
and so on

Your console tool must be converting it

Comment: There is no functions defined as I never defined any.

Comment: Interesting! Will check it out when I get to the office.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I remind correctly, you can see that your "64 length" output is composed from numbers only, there was something about PHPMyAdmin reading the result as binary.

Hopefully you'll be able to get more informations about this here :

[MD5(RAND()) on MySQL returning only digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685534/md5rand-on-mysql-returning-only-digits)